# Swift 3.0 UnsafeMutableRawPointer in Case Switch

Tags: ios, xcode, swift3, key-value-observing, unsafe-pointers

Following works in Swift 3.0:

```
override func observeValue(forKeyPath keyPath: String?, of object: Any?, change: [NSKeyValueChangeKey : Any]?, context: UnsafeMutableRawPointer?)
    {
        if context == &MyContext1 {
        .........
        }
        else if context == &MyContext2 {
        .........
        }
}
```

However, since I have many conditions, if I use switch/case like this:

```
override func observeValue(forKeyPath keyPath: String?, of object: Any?, change: [NSKeyValueChangeKey : Any]?, context: UnsafeMutableRawPointer?)
    {
        switch context {
           case &MyContext1 :
                ........
           case &MyContext2 :
                ........
        }
    }
```

I get an error in regards to UnsafeMutableRawPointer not being able to convert to an integer.

Declarations:

```
private var MyContext1 = 0
private var MyContext2 = 0
```

Comment: Have you considered posting the actual error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When unwrapping `context` the code compiles fine:

```
private var MyContext1 = 0
private var MyContext2 = 0

func observeValue(forKeyPath keyPath: String?, of object: Any?, change: [NSKeyValueChangeKey : Any]?, context: UnsafeMutableRawPointer?) {
    switch context! {
    case &MyContext1 : break
        //
    case &MyContext2 : break
    //
    default: break
    }
}
```